# Left alignment of y-labels in Matplotlib causes text overlap on chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Having trouble having a y-tick label left aligned on a Matplotlib chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textwrap import wrap

labels = ['\n'.join(wrap('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 25))]

ind = [1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(1, 10)

fontdict = {
    'verticalalignment': 'center',
    'horizontalalignment': 'left'}
ax.set_yticks(ind)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels=labels, fontdict=fontdict)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I move the label to not overlay on the chart?

Comment: try this:`ax.set_yticklabels(labels=labels, ha='right',va='center')`

Comment: Not quite. It stops the overlap with the chart, but you loose the left alignment of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment helped me understand what you want. You want to move the label to the left while left-aligning it. I set the position values manually.

```
ax.set_yticklabels(labels=labels, ha='left',va='center', position=(-0.35,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I definitely could've been clearer with the question in retrospect.